# How do I know what wood was used to construct our attic? Need to know how much load it can tolerate

Tags: framing

I'm reading a book and it lists different max loads for different woods.
It lists loads for (1) Douglass Fir-Larch and (2) Hem-fir
My attic is made with a dark brown wood. How do I know what type of wood was used to construct the attic?

The house was built in 1939 in Southern California (don't know if this helps to identify it)

Here's a picture of the attic.  (Could it be redwood?)
[image]

Comment: None of my business, but what kind of load are you contemplating? (I'm concerned that you have something so heavy that we might suggest engineering help, rather than diy...)

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Not planning on adding now. Just want to know for my own knowledge in case we decide on something in the future.

Comment: Happy to hear it. While you get outliers in wood like balsa and ironwood, most construction lumber (spruce, pine, fir, hemlock, even redwood) is pretty much the same from a functional perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not redwood it looks like fir. At the age of the house almost the wood was fir back then. Nice tight grain like what you have is almost impossible to purchase now unless you just won the lottery.

Comment: What do people use for framing attics these days? Just curious.

Comment: Fir is still the standard for framing but the trees are much smaller and the grain is not as tight or clear (knots in the wood). Hem fir is also used but it tends to twist if wet so if used for framing it is best if kiln dryed.